# How can I "merge" two fields when a form is submitted?

Tags: entities, nodes, rules

I have a form from a unique content type which has two fields, when I submit that form, I wish the value entered in the second field was "included" in the end of the first field and then the content type saves.

Like

```
field1, value: "John"
field2, value: "Doo"
```

but when the content type is saved, this happens:

```
field1, value: "John Doo" // the space which divide the two words is required as well.
field2, value: "Doo"
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) for this. Write this function somewhere in your custom module, just print the $node array. You would found all the fields value there that you can alter accordingly. Your code should be something like this.

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'content type name') {
   // Append last name field value with first name field.
  }
}
```

This hook function get executed before node_save() that will save your changes in db.

Answer (score 1):

[Hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) would be another option. You can grab the form values in a custom submit handler.  Code would look something like this:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id)
{
     if($form_id == "your_node_form_id")
     {
          $form['#submit'][] = '_yourmodule_form_custom_submit_handler';
     }
}

function _yourmodule_form_custom_submit_handler($form,$form_state)
{
     //here you can grab and alter the $form_state values accordingly
}
```